# how to 'load data infile' on amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-error-1045

not sure if this is a question better suited for serverfault but I've been messing with amazon RDS lately and was having trouble getting 'file' privileges to my web host mysql user.

I'd assume that a simple:

```
grant file on *.* to 'webuser@'%';
```

would work but it does not and I can't seem to do it with my 'root' user as well. What gives? The reason we use load data is because it is super super fast for doing thousands of inserts at once.

anyone know how to remedy this or do I need to find a different way?

This page, http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?Concepts.DBInstance.html seems to suggest that I need to find a different way around this.

Help?

**UPDATE**
I'm not trying to import a database -- I just want to use the file load option to insert several hundred-thousand rows at a time.

after digging around this is what we have:

```
 mysql> grant file on *.* to 'devuser'@'%';
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)


 mysql> select User, File_priv, Grant_priv, Super_priv from mysql.user;
 +----------+-----------+------------+------------+
 | User     | File_priv | Grant_priv | Super_priv |
 +----------+-----------+------------+------------+
 | rdsadmin | Y         | Y          | Y          |
 | root     | N         | Y          | N          |
 | devuser  | N         | N          | N          |
 +----------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 94):

You need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` as the file is not on the MySQL server, but is on the machine you are running the command from.

As per comment below you may also need to include the flag:

```
--local-infile=1
```

Comment: You also need to use the --local-infile=1 flag on the mysql client, otherwise you get "ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

Comment: @chrisfinne I get PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden in /...Statement.php on line 165

Comment: @eyberg Could you 'Accept' this answer?

Comment: If using MySql Workbench see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408954/1033684

Answer (score 9):

For whatever it's worth... You can add the LOCAL operand to the LOAD DATA INFILE instead of using `mysqlimport` to get around this problem.

LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE ...

This will work without granting FILE permissions.

Comment: thanks for highlighting the LOCAL, missed it when comparing my statement

Answer (score 9):

Also struggled with this issue, trying to upload .csv data into AWS RDS instance from my local machine using **MySQL Workbench** on Windows.

The addition I needed was adding `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` in: Connection > Advanced > Others. Note CAPS was required.

I found this answer by [PeterMag in AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=942113#jive-message-942113).

---

*For further info:*

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` already returned `ON`
and the query was:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filepath/file.csv' 
    INTO TABLE `table_name`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Copying from the answer source referenced above:

> Apparently this is a bug in MYSQL Workbench V8.X. In addition to the
>   configurations shown earlier in this thread, you also need to change
>   the MYSQL Connection in Workbench as follows:
>
> 1. Go to the Welcome page of MYSQL which displays all your connections
> 2. Select Manage Server Connections (the little spanner icon)
> 3. Select your connection
> 4. Select Advanced tab
> 5. In the Others box, add OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1
>
> Now I can use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query on MYSQL RDS. It seems
>   that the File_priv permission is not required.*

Comment: if you are getting an error that table doesn't exist you can define the schema on the table you're inserting into like this : `INTO TABLE \`replication\`.\`master_catalog\``

Answer (score 6):

Pretty sure you can't do it yet, as you don't have the highest level MySQL privileges with RDS. We've only done a little testing, but the easiest way to import a database seems to be to pipe it from the source box, e.g.

```
mysqldump MYDB | mysql -h rds-amazon-blah.com --user=youruser --pass=thepass
```

Comment: yeh... but I'm just trying to load a couple hundred to a couple thousand statements at once -- not really load a db

Comment: I'd run them with a prepared statement then - it won't take long :)

Answer (score 2):

Importing bulk data into Amazon MySQL RDS is possible two ways. You could choose anyone of below as per your convenience.

1. Using Import utility.

   ```
   mysqlimport --local --compress  -u <user-name> -p<password> -h <host-address> <database-name> --fields-terminated-by=',' TEST_TABLE.csv
   --Make sure, here the utility will be inserting the data into TEST_TABLE only.
   ```
2. Sending a bulk insert SQL by piping into into mysql command.

   ```
   mysql -u <user-name> -p<password> -h <host-address> <database-name> < TEST_TABLE_INSERT.SQL
   --Here file TEST_TABLE_INSERT.SQL will have bulk import sql statement like below
   --insert into TEST_TABLE values('1','test1','2017-09-08'),('2','test2','2017-09-08'),('3','test3','2017-09-08'),('3','test3','2017-09-08');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues. I was in fact trying to import a database but the conditions should be the same - I needed to use load data due to the size of some tables, a spotty connection, and the desire for a modest resume functionality.

I agree with chris finne that not specifying the local option can lead to that error. After many fits and starts I found that the mk-parallel-restore tool from [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/maatkit.html) provided what I needed with some excellent extra features. It might be a great match for your use case.