# Connect with local-infile Option in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to connect with the local-infile Option in MySql Workbench? Like this:

```
mysql -h 10.152.xx.xx -u USER -p --local-infile MyDatabase
```

The reason is, that LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE seems to work only with this option. Even if

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

returns

```
'local_infile', 'ON'
```

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE yields

```
Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Comment: Both server and client options need to be set. The global variable is enabled "ON",  on the server; in addition, you would need to enable the client connection param as well.

Answer (score 20):

Edit the connection settings in MySQL Workbench.

Under the Advanced tab, add the following option to the connector options in the others window:

OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1

Comment: Thanks, works for me on MySQL workbench 8.0 on macOS.

Answer (score 10):

This not working is a verified [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891) since Workbench 8.0.12. Solution from the bug's comments:

> Both the server and the client can restrict use of the LOCAL keyword for LOAD DATA and LOAD XML. The same error message is produced if either one blocks it.
>
> To cause the server to permit access, set the local_infile variable with `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;` or check it with `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';`. Alternatively, edit mysql's config to include `local_infile=1`.
>
> To cause Workbench to permit access, edit the connection (click the wrench icon by the MySQL Connections, or right-click on a particular connection and choose Edit Connection...). On the Advanced tab, in the "Others:" box, add the line `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1`

I just ran into this problem and setting the variable as well as the MySQL Workbench config solved it.

Comment: how did you get it to save the option you added in the edit connection screen? I see where I need to add it, but there's no 'save' button and when i click out of it, it just removes any changes i made

Comment: Can't help you here; my work environment for this one is long gone. Maybe someone else can answer your question?

Comment: >Alternatively, edit mysql's config to include local_infile=1.

This worked for me on MacOS. Make sure to set the config file path in system preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL Workbench 8.0.12 (more recent encountering of this issue), this bug might explain,

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891

I just upgraded from MySQLWorkbench 6.x to 8.0.12, and the LOCAL INFILE broke with "Error code 1148. The used command is not allowed with the MySQL version." without any other changes (GLOBAL variable local_infile is ON).

P.S. I also tried with the local_infile=1 parameter in the Advanced preferences, and it does not resolve the issue. For the time being, I rolled back to the older version of workbench till the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add that parameter to the connection settings (Advanced -> Others)? Haven't done this myself yet, but worth trying:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the `AllowLoadLocalInfile=true` flag in the client's connection string. You can add this parameter by going to connection settings (Advanced -> Others) and pasting the following line at the bottom:

`AllowLoadLocalInfile=true`

By default, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" is disabled because it poses a security risk. A malicious server or proxy could send a fake “local infile request” packet to the client and read any file that the client has permission to open. So you have to manually allow it by adding the flag above.