# MySQL 8: Enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

[image]I am using Mac with mysql workbench 8.0.19

when i run this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/Users/raianazaman/Desktop/DataBase/Sample.txt'  INTO TABLE employee
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 0 LINES;
```

i get this error:
Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

I have run this:
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
and it shows: 'local_infile','ON'

Comment: Have you enabled `loca_infile` for the MySQL workbench application?

Comment: I have run this: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'; and it shows: 'local_infile','ON'

Comment: But what about this setting in your client, in this case the MySQL workbench? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html#load-data-local-configuration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450389/connect-with-local-infile-option-in-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 1):

> I have run this: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'; and it shows: 'local_infile','ON'

I think you can run `mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p` and try to load file again. It works for me.

[image]