# Response like that `Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.' When I load the data from CSV

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the code below in MySQL5.0, I will have a response like:

> Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Downloads\2013-07 - Citi Bike Trip Data.csv'  
INTO TABLE citibike.stations   
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   
IGNORE 1 ROWS  
(@id, @startstationname, @startstationlatitude, @startstationlongitude)    
SET   
     id = @id,  
     Name =@startstationname,  
     Latitude=@startstationlatitude,  
     Longitude=@startstationlongitude;
```

I already set the local infile to On, but still not working, do I need to still change any parameter?

Comment: The user needs the `FILE` privilege.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: This might not have been the OP problem but it's something that produces the same error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408954/1033684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution finally, we need to go to the MySQL Command Line Client (My version is 5.7), and change all the `\`  in the path to `/`, like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Downloads/2013-07 - Citi Bike Trip Data.csv'
```

In the workbench and cell will show us the different error, in the cell, the response is Error 1148, in the workbench is 2068.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve this in script?  A way to set a safe directory, for example?