# error code 2068 local infile file rejected due to restrictions on access

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run the following script

```
# Truncate is used to remove all records if already the table exists
TRUNCATE records;
#Change the path to your file location 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\amanda.ramos\Desktop\EdX_Enrollment.csv'

INTO TABLE records
# Each column in a CSV file is separated by ','
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
# Each line in a CSV file is separated by '\n'
#LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
# Because we want to ignore the header of the .csv file. If your .csv does not have a header remove this line
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

but I am getting an error message saying: 'error code: load data local infile file requested rejected due to restrictions on access.  I tried running the following  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'; and it shows local_infile ON. Not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Run it without the LOCAL, you are already local

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect with local-infile Option in MySql Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450389/connect-with-local-infile-option-in-mysql-workbench)