# Bulk Load CSV file from S3 to AWS RDS - MySQL Database using python code

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

We are trying to Load a CSV file (huge file) from Amazon S3 to an Amazon RDS mySQL database. We are not supposed to use Data Pipeline, so we need python code to load data. So instead of reading file row by row, we need an alternative way to load file in a bulk way.

We tried to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command but its not working:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Desktop\\TestMySQL.csv
INTO TABLE test_db.departments
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
```

Expecting a simple command (if we have any) to load data from S3 to MySQL RDS database, like Aurora DB.

Comment: It looks like you will need to use an SQL client or SQL utility to load the data. The above command won't work because it is run on the server, which has no access to files on your own computer (`C:\`). See: [Importing Data into a MySQL DB Instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Other.html)

Comment: The `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` read the file from the local client machine, not the server.   Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641160/how-to-load-data-infile-on-amazon-rds  you should add the `--local-infile=1` option to mysql command line client.  However, this does not address your issue of loading the file from S3.